# Docker - how to set up Apache + PHP in docker-compose.yml

Tags: php, apache, docker, docker-compose, ubuntu-16.04

I use this to set up nginx for PHP:

```
nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
        - 8080:80
    volumes:
        - ./code:/code
        - ./site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf
    links:
        - php
php:
    image: php:7-fpm
    volumes:
        - ./code:/code
```

But how about Apache? How can I set up Apache + PHP in docker-compose.yml?

Following this [guide](https://www.kinamo.be/en/support/faq/setting-up-a-development-environment-with-docker-compose):

```
version: '2'

services:
  php:
    build: php
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./php/www:/var/www/html
```

Error:

```
ERROR: In file './docker-compose.yml' service 'version' doesn't have any configuration options. All top level keys in your docker-compose.yml must map to a dictionary of configuration options.
```

Any ideas? I'm on Xubuntu 16.04.

**EDIT:**

After managing to upgrade docker-compose to 1.9, I try with this file below:

```
version: '2'
services:
    php:
        build: php
        expose:
            - 9000
        volumes:
            - ./php/www:/var/www/html

    apache2:
        image: webdevops/apache:latest
        args:
            - PHP_SOCKET=php:9000
        volumes:
            - ./php/www:/var/www/html
        ports:
            - 80:80
            - 443:443
        links:
            - php
```

Error:

```
$ sudo docker-compose up -d
Building php
ERROR: Cannot locate specified Dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

Docker is such as pain!

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 13):

Since the example above does not work for me, here is a different approach:

Your file `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  php:
    image: php:apache
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./php/www:/var/www/html/
```

Launch the server with

```
docker-compose up
```

This works with a single Docker image and a single service, since there is already an official PHP image based on latest Debian GNU/Linux stable and with Apache HTTPd webserver. Info:

https://hub.docker.com/_/php

Answer (score 7):

I would choose webdevops dockerized [apache](https://github.com/webdevops/Dockerfile/tree/develop/docker/apache), because it has simple configuration:

```
version: '2'
services:
    php:
        build: php
        expose:
            - 9000
        volumes:
            - ./php/www:/var/www/html

    apache2:
        image: webdevops/apache:latest
        args:
            - PHP_SOCKET=php:9000
        volumes:
            - ./php/www:/var/www/html
        ports:
            - 80:80
            - 443:443
        links:
            - php
```

Comment: thanks. I have just tried that but I get the same error `ERROR: In file './docker-compose.yml' service 'version' doesn't have any configuration options. All top level keys in your docker-compose.yml must map to a dictionary of configuration options.`

Comment: Looks like yours docker compose version is lower than 1.6. Docker compose version 2 is only available since 1.6 docker compose. Check version `docker-compose --version`

Comment: you are right - it is `docker-compose version 1.5.2, build unknown` so how can I upgrade it?

Comment: Try this tut: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-compose-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: thanks but it doesn't mention about upgrading docker-compose to v2.

Comment: For anyone stumbling on this later, the [Compose file version](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/#versioning) does not match the `docker-compose` version, e.g. [`version: '2'`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/#version-2) corresponds to `docker-compose 1.6.0+`

Comment: I get this error: "Unsupported config option for services.apache2: 'args'"

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/45978518/6478501

Answer (score 1):

1. We need to create a new folders /php/www in current path
2. Create a file under php folder save as "Dockerfile" which contains as below without quote

"FROM php:5.6-apache
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli"

3. Copy your docker-compose.yml file in your current folder where your "php" folder has.
4. Create a sample file "index.php" under www folder (/php/www/index.php)
5. Run in command prompt docker-compose up -d
6. Open your browser type "localhost" you can see your sample file results.

Note: Above steps as per above mentioned docker-compose.yml file.

Comment: It is not recommended to use 2 containers ?, one for apache and one for php?

Answer (score 0):

You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34316047/difference-between-image-and-build-within-docker-compose#:%7E:text=build%3A%20expects%20dockerfile%20path%20as,launch%20container%20using%20this%20image.) question.
If you use **build** instead of **image**, then you need "Dockerfile". **Dockerfile** would be use as configuration file for building image.

You maybe miss part in guide, where you should **create file** with name "Dockerfile" **inside directory** "php". Directory "php" must be in the same directory, where your "docker-compose.yml". In "docker-compose.yml" you have this line.

```
build: php
```

The line mean, that configuration file (by default: "Dockerfile") is inside of directory "php". So you should create directory "php" and file "Dockerfile" inside of it.

This is "Dockerfile" from [your guide](https://www.kinamo.be/en/support/faq/setting-up-a-development-environment-with-docker-compose).

```
FROM php:5.6-apache

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli
```

[docker-compose.yml reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/) version 2

[Dockerfile reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/)

Answer (score 0):

I found an elegant way to dynamically configure the ports and other parameters: In apache2's configuration files you can reference environment variables.

```
#/etc/apache2/ports.conf
# If you just change the port or add more ports here, you will likely also
# have to change the VirtualHost statement in
# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
#APACHE_HTTP_PORT_NUMBER:80
#APACHE_HTTPS_PORT_NUMBER:443

Listen ${APACHE_HTTP_PORT_NUMBER}


<IfModule ssl_module>
    Listen ${APACHE_HTTPS_PORT_NUMBER}
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen ${APACHE_HTTPS_PORT_NUMBER}
</IfModule>
```

you can set the variables in Dockerfile or docker-compose.yml

Answer (score -1):

You can set a directory with diferente Dockerfiles an declare in each service:

```
...
    image: php:custom
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./dockerfiles/Dockerfile-php
...
```

Answer (score -1):

I have created a working example of PHP, APACHE, MYSQL, and PHPMYADMIN for PHP developers. You may find it useful if you need the original old-school working style. Please note that I am using port 8080 for my website and port 8081 for PHPMyAdmin. You can change these as you like.

```
version: '3.8'


services:


 php-apache-environment:
container_name: php-apache
image: php:7.4-apache
volumes:
  - ./php/src:/var/www/html/
ports:
  - 8080:80
  db:
image: mysql
command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
container_name: mysql
environment:
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin
  MYSQL_DATABASE: ezapi
  MYSQL_USER: root
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
ports:
  - "6033:3306"
volumes:
  - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql


phpmyadmin:
image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
container_name: phpmyadmin
links:
  - mysql
environment:
  PMA_HOST: mysql
  PMA_PORT: 3306
  PMA_ARBITRARY: 1
restart: always
ports:
  - 8081:80
volumes:


 dbdata:
```