# unable to build docker-compose build

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm getting this error when I tried  to `docker-compose build` my docker-compose.yml file:

```
In file './docker-compose.yml' service 'version' doesn't have any configuration options. All top level keys in your docker-compose.yml must map to a dictionary of configuration options.
```

docker version

Client:
 Version:      1.12.6
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.3
 Git commit:   78d1802
 Built:        Tue Jan 31 23:47:34 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.12.6
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.3
 Git commit:   78d1802
 Built:        Tue Jan 31 23:47:34 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

docker --version
Docker version 1.12.6, build 78d1802

docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.5.2, build unknown

is this because the build unknown?

docker-composer.yml

```
version: "2"

services:
    postgres:
        image: postgres:9.6
        volumes:
          - pgdata:/var/lib/data/postgres

    backend:
        build: .
        command: gosu app bash
        volumes:
            - .:/app
            - pyenv:/python
        links:
          - postgres:postgres
        ports:
          - 8000:8000

volumes:
    pyenv:
    pgdata:
```

Comment: can we see the docker-compose.yml?

Comment: @whites11 version: "2"

services:
    postgres:
        image: postgres:9.6
        volumes:
          - pgdata:/var/lib/data/postgres

    backend:
        build: .
        command: gosu app bash
        volumes:
            - .:/app
            - pyenv:/python
        links:
          - postgres:postgres
        ports:
          - 8000:8000

volumes:
    pyenv:
    pgdata:

Comment: post it in the question, with proper formatting, please

Comment: how are you indenting ? with tabs? try indenting with 2 spaces.

Comment: I think the issue is related with version not indentation @whites11

Comment: @whites11 after indenting with 2 spaces I'm getting this ERROR: yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here
  in "./docker-compose.yml", line 6, column 14

Comment: I have noticed on thing, when I try to indent it with 2 spaces it shows this error:yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here
  in "./docker-compose.yml", line 6, column 14   And when I do indentation with tabs it shows this error:In file './docker-compose.yml' service 'version' doesn't have any configuration options. All top level keys in your docker-compose.yml must map to a dictionary of configuration options.   PLEASE HELP ME I REALLY DON'T KNOW WHATS HAPPENING.

Comment: indent with 2 spaces (avoid tabs, they're not yaml standard) and ensure you have valid yml by using a tool such as http://www.yamllint.com/

Comment: @whites11 yamllint.com says its a valid yml

Comment: and what error do you have now?

Comment: @whites11 In file './docker-compose.yml' service 'version' doesn't have any configuration options. All top level keys in your docker-compose.yml must map to a dictionary of configuration options.

Comment: ok you need to upgrade docker-compose, check other responses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try upgrading the docker-compose version. Version 2 files are supported by Compose 1.6.0+ and require a Docker Engine of version 1.10.0+.

Install latest "docker-compose" -

```
$ sudo curl -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.15.0/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)"
$ sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

Ref- 
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/#version-2

Comment: docker --version
Docker version 1.12.6, build 78d1802

Comment: docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.5.2, build unknown

Comment: please suggest me which docker compose version should I install

Comment: You need to purge your current "docker-compose" & install the latest version using above commands. Method of purging depends on the way you installed "docker-compose" .

Comment: Anything above 1.6.0 should work. I would suggest you to go for 1.10+ .

Comment: what to do after sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose? it is still showing the previous version

Comment: Are you trying this with user "root" ? Do a `which docker-compose` & place this new binary within the respective bin folder OR try creating a symlink.

Comment: okay my which docker-compose is: /usr/local/bin/docker-compose Do i need to go to this directory and execute above commands.please be more specific as I'm new to this

Comment: Remove the file "/usr/local/bin/docker-compose" and try running the above two commands again.

Answer (score 0):

You should install docker-compose using the official documentation https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/

If you are using linux, I have found the apt install for docker-compose shows some weird behavior. So uninstall docker-compose and reinstall it using the official documentation above.

```
sudo apt-get purge docker-compose
```

Comment: This solved my issue. I uninstalled docker-compose then reinstalled it again and ran build command with sudo.Thank you so much